# tell grails maven plugin to use servlet 2.5 instead of 3.0

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets, grails

I might have a stupid and really obvious question:

I basically have a grails 2.3.8 project, build using maven 3.2, with the grails maven plugin 2.4.3

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.grails</groupId>
            <artifactId>grails-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Whether for Fork a JVM to run Grails commands -->
                <fork>true</fork>
                <grailsVersion>${grails.version}</grailsVersion>
            </configuration>
            <extensions>true</extensions>

        </plugin>
```

when I do a

```
mvn clean install
```

I keep getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/AsyncContext
   at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2484)
   at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1827)
   at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
```

my BuildConfig specifies grails to utilize, servlet 2.5

grails.servlet.version = "2.5"

and all my test's are working fine, if I run them from grails directly using:

grails test-app :integration

but fail with the given exception, if I run them from the command line

mvn clean install

my dependency report lists the correct servlet version:

```
javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
```

anybody has an idea how to solve this?

thanks